# App Tethering работает только в локальной сети?

Tags: сеть

App Tethering работает только в локальной сети?

Если приложение 1 находится за маршрутизатором №1, 
приложение 2 за маршрутизатором №2 (в разных локальных сетях), смогут ли они соединится?﻿

Comment: Добавь больше информации. Короткий ответ для данной формулировки вопроса - да. Нужно будет прописать маршрут.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_App_Tethering

Comment: ПробОвал, у меня не получается, пожалуйста Можете на примере показать.